# Same css is rendering different fonts

Tags: css, npm, fonts, font-family

I was using `Open Sans`font from http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans. Some of client used closed environments due to security reasons so I need to use local fonts which I used installed from npm.

I have tried multiple packages from npm for `Open Sans` like `"open-sans-all": "^0.1.3"`, `"typeface-open-sans": "^0.0.54"`but fonts with same css are different from previous rendering with fonts from GoogleApis, particularly when `font-weight: bold;` is applied.

I am images of difference.

[image]

[image]

There is no `HTTP 404` for any resources & all fonts & resources are downloading properly.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong so that same font with same css is rendering differently?

Comment: One version is _probably_ rendered faux-bold by the browser (i.e. it's artificially rendered bold as an actual bold version of the font doesn't exist). The other version is _probably_ being rendered using an actual bold font as one exists. The _fonts.googleapis_ url provided doesn't include an actual bold version of the font, yet the npm one _(open-sans-all)_ does. As you haven't provided a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I think your question is open to guesstimate answers, if any at all. Perhaps add the `@fontface` Rules and CSS Rulesets used to your OP. Might help get an answer.

Comment: @RobC you are correct, it is probably faux-bold by the browser as there is specific bold definition exist in Font from npm but nothing in GoogleApi one. It is lame but client preferred old one i.e. faux from browser so need to download same woff2 file & referred locally but again need to add extra EOT file for IE as woff are not recognized by IE & chrome doesn't recognize EOT

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Pranav. _"...client preferred old one"_ sounds familiar to me. I've had a similar scenario with a client too. I typically now choose a font family with a variety of weights/styles (bold, semibold, italic, etc) which are supported by all browsers. I declare them in `@font-face` rules and reference them explicitly in each ruleset i.e. `.quux { font-family: 'SomeFontBold'}` instead of `.quux { font-family: 'SomeFont'; font-weight: bold;}`. I try where possible to avoid using the declarations `font-weight: bold;` and `font-style: italic;` to avoid possible faux rendering.

Comment: That is great recommendation, I will try same in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @RobC mentioned, it is probably faux-bold by the browser as there is specific bold definition exist in Font from npm but nothing in GoogleApi one.

It is lame but client preferred old one i.e. faux from browser so need to download same woff2 file & referred locally after downloading from site like :

1. open http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans
2. It has different font faces used like :

   ```
   /* cyrillic-ext */
   @font-face {
     font-family: 'Open Sans';
     font-style: normal;
     font-weight: 400;
     src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFWJ0bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
     unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
   } ...
   ```
3. download all files locally mentioned in url as resource like below:

http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFWJ0bbck.woff2

4. modify original css to use local resources like :

   `@font-face {
     font-family: 'Open Sans';
     font-style: normal;
     font-weight: 400;
     src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(ui/fonts/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFWJ0bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
     unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
   }`

but again need to add extra EOT file for InternetExplorer as woff2 are not recognized by IE & chrome doesn't recognize EOT